# Core Plot Header Search Paths, what does it mean recursive?

Tags: ios, graph, header, core-plot, search-path

Trying to add `CorePlot` to my application in iOS.  Using Xcode 4.3.3.

I think I successfully followed all the steps except adding the Header Search Paths.

Most of the tutorials seem to be for an older version of xcode.

I put `${PROJECT_DIR}/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework` into my Search Paths.  Is that what is meant by a recursive path?

In the settings it shows boxes for Ad Hoc, Debug, and Release.  Do you need to add the same thing three times?

I realize this question has come up on stack overflow, but I read those other questions and I still couldn't figure it out

Right now I'm getting this error "`CPTAnnotation.h`" file not found.  Before I changed the search path to what I wrote above, then I got a message about CorePlot itself not being found, so at least that's a step up.
I tried with two asterisks after the path "**" but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out.  You're supposed to add a slash before the two asterisks.

i.e. ${PROJECT_DIR}/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework/**

That was fun...

I put the CorePlot folder in same folder as my project.  You have to modify the path if you're not putting it there.

Also, if you can't see how to add Header Search Paths in your project settings, make sure to click "All" at the bar at the top, instead of "Basic".